# How to select 3 tables in sql

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT a.ssmid, a.image,b.ssmid,b.image,c.ssmid,c.image FROM a user_photos_offline INNER JOIN user_profile_pic b on a.ssmid = b.ssmid INNER JOIN user_family_photos c on a.ssmid = c.ssmid");

  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
      echo $row['image'];
  }
```

I want select all images from DB,i have 3 tables, these are the table names `user_photos_offline`, `user_profile_pic`, `user_family_photos` and column name is `image` for all tables.

And in 3 tables I have same column of `ssmid`, now I want select the images for these 3 tables

Comment: Shouldn't the table column name first before the shortcut name? `user_photos_offline a` instead of `a user_photos_offline`?

Answer (score 0):

To refer to the images seperately, use `AS`:

```
SELECT 
  a.ssmid, a.image AS a_image, 
  b.ssmid, b.image AS b_image, 
  c.ssmid, c.image AS c_image
 FROM user_photos_offline a
 INNER JOIN user_profile_pic b on a.ssmid = b.ssmid 
 INNER JOIN user_family_photos c on a.ssmid = c.ssmid
```

In PHP, your index would change to these identifiers:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
     echo $row['a_image'];
     echo $row['b_image'];
     echo $row['c_image'];
}
```

Comment: There's a typo - `a-image` should be `a_image` :) Happy coding! ;)

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\matrimonial\new\KANI\image-cropper\index.php

Comment: Oops, sorry, missed the shift key. Thanks to the editor.

Comment: @KanniyappanRamasamy You will have to replace the dots with the rest of your query, starting with the `FROM`.

Comment: @KanniyappanRamasamy did you tried syck's query as is ?

Comment: Now included the rest of the query.

Comment: Copied your error from above where the alias is before the table name instead of after, as @LoganWayne commented. Corrected it now. Echoing  `mysql_error()` after the query might help you find errors in your SQL.

Comment: Now its working fine ya,but all images i moved to three different folder,how to show the img tag –

Answer (score 0):

If there is no relation between `ssmid` in each of your tables `user_photos_offline`, `user_profile_pic` and `user_family_photos`, no need to use [`INNER JOIN`](http://sql.sh/cours/jointures/inner-join). Use [`UNION`](http://sql.sh/cours/union) instead:

```
$sql=mysql_query(
    "SELECT ssmid, image, CONCAT('folder1/', image) as image_filename FROM user_photos_offline
    UNION
    SELECT ssmid, image, CONCAT('folder2/', image) as image_filename FROM user_profile_pic
    UNION
    SELECT ssmid, image, CONCAT('folder3/', image) as image_filename FROM user_family_photos"
    );

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    echo $row['image'];
    echo $row['image_filename'];
}
```

Comment: K its is working fine,but all images i moved to three different folder,how to show the img tag

Comment: you can create another field image_filename. See changes on my answer

Comment: You can mark this answer as a solution if it works for you ;)